# What is the most efficient way to get a random odd or even number?

Tags: objective-c

So off the top of my head, I can think of a few solutions (focusing on getting random odd numbers for example):

```
int n;
while (n == 0 || n % 2 == 0) {
    n = (arc4random() % 100);
}
```

eww.. right?  Not efficient at all..

```
int n = arc4random() % 100);
if (n % 2 == 0) n += 1;
```

But I don't like that it's always going to increase the number if it's not odd..  Maybe that shouldn't matter?  Another approach could be to randomize that:

```
int n = arc4random() % 100);
if (n % 2 == 0) {
    if (arc4random() % 2 == 0) {
       n += 1;
    else {
       n -= 1;
    }
 }
```

But this feels a little bleah to me..  So I am wondering if there is a better way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: Example output desired, please. "odd *or* even" in the title is confusing.

Comment: printf("%d\n", ((rand() % 5) + 1) * 2 + 1);

Answer (score 6):

Generate a random number and then multiply it by two for even, multiply by two plus 1 for odd.

In general, you want to keep these simple or you run the risk of messing up the distribution of numbers.  Take the output of the typical [0...1) random number generator and then use a function to map it to the desired range.

FWIW - It doesn't look like you're skewing the distributions above, except for the third one.  Notice that getting 99 is less probable than all the others unless you do your adjustments with a modulus incl. negative numbers.  Since..

```
P(99) = P(first roll = 99) + P(first roll = 100 & second roll = -1) + P(first roll = 98 & second roll = +1)
```

and `P(first roll = 100) = 0`

Answer (score 3):

If you want a random set of binary digits followed by a fixed digit, then I'd go with bitwise operations:

```
 odd = arc4random() | 1; 
 even = arc4random() & ~ 1;
```